# Javascript Submit on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, submit

I have the next code:

```
document.myForm.mySubmit.click();
```

Where myForm - form name, mySubmit - submit name. I want to call submit of my form outside me form. My problem - my form doesn't have names(terrible?). How can I do this with help of id or classes?

Or may be you know another way?

Thank you.

Comment: show some concise version of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give the form an "id" you can:

```
 var form = document.getElementById('yourIdValue');
 form.mySubmit.click();
```

Comment: Now you `click` on the form? Will that submit it? I'd use the `submit` method.

Answer (score 1):

better yet you can just use the submit method.
no need for the button.

```
var currForm = document.getElementById('yourIdValue');
currForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
$('#my_button').click(
    function()
    {
        $('#my_form').trigger('onsubmit');
        // Or 
        $('#my_form').onsubmit();
       // or 
        $('#my_form').trigger('onSubmit');
       // or  even --
        $('#my_form').submit();
    }
 );
```